# Join vectors into dataframe by matching values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I'm trying to compare multiple vectors to see where there are matching values between them. I'd like to combine the vectors into a table where every column either has the same value (for matches) or NA (for no match).

For example:

```
list1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
list2 <- c("a", "c", "d")
list3 <- c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f")
```

Should become:

```
a  a  a
b NA  b
c  c  c
d  d  NA
NA NA e
NA NA f
```

I've tried making the vectors dataframes and using `merge`, `join` from `dplyr`, `cbind`, `cbind.fill`, but all those either return a single column or don't match values across all rows.

What's the best way to get this result with R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Base R` solution:

```
df1 = data.frame(col = list1, list1)
df2 = data.frame(col = list2, list2)
df3 = data.frame(col = list3, list3)

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))

#   col list1 list2 list3
# 1   a     a     a     a
# 2   b     b  <NA>     b
# 3   c     c     c     c
# 4   d     d     d  <NA>
# 5   e  <NA>  <NA>     e
# 6   f  <NA>  <NA>     f
```

**Result:**

```
> Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))[,-1]
  list1 list2 list3
1     a     a     a
2     b  <NA>     b
3     c     c     c
4     d     d  <NA>
5  <NA>  <NA>     e
6  <NA>  <NA>     f
```

or with `dplyr` + `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list(list1, list2, list3) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(col = ., ., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "col") %>%
  select(-col) %>%
  setNames(paste0("list", 1:3))
```

**Data:**

```
list1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
list2 <- c("a", "c", "d")
list3 <- c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f")
```

Comment: Just add `[,-1]` at the end of your function.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks, I wanted to make it clear what `Reduce` is actually doing

Answer (score 6):

You can use `unlist` and `unique` to get all possible values, then find their matches across each of the vectors. If nothing matches, `match` returns `NA` like you want:

```
list1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
list2 <- c("a", "c", "d")
list3 <- c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f")
list_of_lists <- list(
  list1 = list1,
  list2 = list2,
  list3 = list3
)

all_values <- unique(unlist(list_of_lists))

fleshed_out <- vapply(
  list_of_lists,
  FUN.VALUE = all_values,
  FUN       = function(x) {
    x[match(all_values, x)]
  }
)

fleshed_out
#    list1 list2 list3
# [1,] "a"   "a"   "a"
# [2,] "b"   NA    "b"
# [3,] "c"   "c"   "c"
# [4,] "d"   "d"   NA
# [5,] NA    NA    "e"
# [6,] NA    NA    "f"
```